# While implementing Queue using Linked List, Why is insertion complexity O(1)?

Tags: c++

I read my book where it is written that insertion and deletion from queue using Linked List both has O(1) complexity but my understanding is for deletion it'll be O(1) but for insertion it is O(n) because it'll traverse till end pointer.

Comment: It must have two pointers, one on each end.

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth then it ll be doubly linked list..for singly LL it is possible or not?

Comment: @ManishGoyal the nodes don't need to be doubly linked, the list itslef just has to keep a pointer to the last node.

Comment: No, it will not be a doubly linked list. A DLL node contains two pointers to the next node and the previous one. In this case you hold a pointer for the head and the tail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When implementing a Queue using a Linked List, the Linked List is the internal data structure that holds the data, since a Queue is FIFO (first-in-first-out) the only requirement is that the elements need to be removed from the head in order and elements need only be added to the tail. A singly linked list is an adequate container for this as it maintains a one way path of pointers through the elements from head to tail. The only requirement for the wrapper Queue then is to hold a reference to the head and a reference to the tail.

When an element is popped/removed, the Queue removes the first element in O(1) time using the head pointer and uses the linked reference to the next element as the new head pointer. When an element is pushed/added, it marks the tail element with a pointer to the new element, in order to maintain an unbroken "queue", and also holds a reference to the added element so that it can add the next element in O(1) time.